# Is this recursion relation proof correct?

Tags: number-theory, discrete-mathematics

Recurrence relation:$$a_0 = 1$$

$$a_{n+1} = 2a_n$$

I'm trying to prove that for any n ∈ N, $a_n = 2^n$.  I want to use induction.

What I have is, assume that $a_n = 2^n$ is true for $P(n)$.

Then $P(n+1)$ would be:

$$a_{n+1} = 2^{n+1}$$

$$a_{n+1}=2\cdot(2^n)$$

Because $a_n = 2^n$, then we can substitute, so $a_{n+1} = 2a_n$.

Comment: Not all even numbers are powers of $2$. For example $6$ isn't. If one is to evaluate your proof, one has to know what $A_n$ represents. Of if $A_n$ was simply *defined* by a recurrence, one needs to know that.

Comment: That is given because this is a recursion problem. I added the recursion definition to the problem.

Comment: Some typos, you want to show that $a_{n+1}=2^{n+1}$ given the induction assumption $a_n=2^n$. So subscripts not right in a couple of the displayed lines.

Comment: @AndréNicolas Thanks, I think I fixed them now.

Comment: @Jose That last sentence is still a mess - it is wrong as stated, and it is unclear what you actually mean by it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The *idea* of the proof is certainly correct. There are some issues, such as the incorrect but unnnecessary assertion that all even numbers are powers of $2$.

We rewrite the proof you gave, making small modifications. After a while, you will not be expected to use the notation $P(n)$ explicitly.

Let $P(n)$ be the assertion that $a_n=2^n$. We prove by induction that $P(n)$ is true for every non-negative integer $n$.

Certainly $P(0)$ is true, since $a_0=1=2^0$.

Suppose that for a particular integer $k$, the assertion $P(k)$ is true. We show that $P(k+1)$ is true.

Since $P(k)$ is true, we have $a_k=2^k$. But then 
$$a_{k+1}=2a_k=2\cdot 2^k =2^{k+1},$$
so $P(k+1)$ is true. This completes the induction step and the proof.

Comment: I noticed in your answer, you are assuming $a_n$ and trying to prove $a_{n+1}$.  I thought it was supposed to be the other way around because $a_{n+1}$ is given to us in the recursion relation.

Comment: There are still problems. The sentence "assume that $a_n = 2^n$ is true for $P(n)$" does not say what you probably intend. You need to explicitly *define* what you mean by $P(n)$, perhaps using wording somewhat like mine. For the rest, the *logic* of your argument is not made clear. This is most obvious at the end, where you seem to reach the conclusion that $a_{n+1}=2a_n$. But we are **given** that fact, it is how the sequence is defined.

Comment: I am not assuming $a_n$, since $a_n$ is not an assertion. I am assuming (if you don't like $k$ you can use $n$, but I think $k$ is clearer) that $P(k)$ holds for a particular $k$, that is that $a_k=2^k$, example $a_7=2^7$. We then use that fact to prove that $a_{k+1}=2^{k+1}$, like $a_8=2^8$.

Comment: So essentially, we are given $a_{n+1}$, and we are trying to prove $a_n$?

Comment: Please remember, $a_i$ is not an assertion, so we are not proving $a_n$. We are **using** the assumption that $a_k=2^k$ to prove that the same relationship holds for the next guy, that is, that $a_{k+1}=2^{k+1}$.   We are going *forward*, as I hope my answer and the one by Thomas Andrews makes clear.

Comment: Part of your problem, at least if you went to a North American high school, is that a certain style of "proof" is taught, in which you start with what you want to prove, and manipulate until you get to something you know to be true. This has the logic backwards. If the steps are reversible, and are **shown** to be reversible, it is not wrong. But that part tends to ne neglected, and one can end up with major errors.

Comment: I understand the logic in the proof; I'm still a bit confused with the structure given the problem's format.  Here is what the actual example problem looks like (https://www.box.com/shared/static/xc82tdf0m6raco3kzfmj.png).  It seems like we are given in the premises, that $a_{n+1} = 2a_n$, and we have to show that $a_n = 2^n$ from that.

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what you need to prove. And that is what is proved in the answer above, and in the answer by Thomas Andrews.

Answer (score 1):

The key to an induction proof is to prove $P(0)$ and then prove that $P(n)\implies P(n+1)$.

$P(0)$ is just the statement that $a_0=2^0$, which is obvious.

Now assume you know $P(n)$ - that is, $a_n = 2^{n}$. Then $a_{n+1}=2a_n = 2(2^n)=2^{n+1}$. Therefore you know $P(n+1)$.

Therefore you are done.

There is nothing needed about even numbers in this proof, just that $2(2^n)=2^{n+1}$.